# (DISCORD.JS V13) client.guilds.cache.get is not working properly

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

Im making a bot in discord.js v13, and i wanted to return client's number of guilds/users/channels.
But it returns `function get() { [native code] }` instead.

```js
        const main = new MessageEmbed()
            .setColor("#6164ab")
            .addField("<:discordReply:971028493645262888> Stats", `• ${client.guilds.cache.get} guilds\n• ${client.users.cache.get} users\n• ${client.channels.cache.get} channels`)

        await interaction.reply({ embeds: [main], ephemeral: true })
```

This is my code.
Thanks.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Discord.JS docs, as i see `guilds.cache` is returning a collection and it has properties to get size. So you can basically get size of guilds with;

```js
client.guilds.cache.size // => Returns number
```

[More info](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/main/class/Collection?scrollTo=get)

Unfortunately, `.get` is method and so it should be `.get()` which is returning **undefined...**

[More info](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/main/class/Collection?scrollTo=get)

Answer (score 1):

The correct property for getting the number of entries turned out to be `.size` and not `.get`.